# How many more operations can 1000 times faster computer perform on a task with T(n)=log₂(n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Lets say we have an algorithm with with time complexity T(n)=log₂(n). In a time T we can solve problem of size n1. How much bigger problem can we solve in the same time T on a 1000 times faster computer (duration time of 1 operation is 1000 faster).

For example if we have a problem T(n) = n³, we can solve 10*n1 problems on a 1000 times faster computer.

```
n2³ = 1000*n1³,
n2 = ³√(1000)*n1,
n2 = 10*n1,
```

But I can't wrap my head around how to calculate logarithmic function.

Comment: Remember that `log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)`. So `log(a^k) = log(a*a*...*a) = log(a) + log(a) + ... + log(a) = k * log(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the same approach:

```
log(n2) = 1000 log(n1)
```

Using log formula:

```
M * log(a) = log(a^M)
```

the above becomes:

```
log(n2) = log(n1^1000)
```

so i guess (n1^1000) operations

Answer (score 0):

```
log(m) = 1000 log(n)
```

can be written

```
m= n^1000
```

(whatever the base).

So for any value of `n`, `m` will exceed the capacity of existing computers.